# Running parameterized queries in QSqlTableModel

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, qt5, qsqltablemodel

I have a `QTableView` and I am using a derived class `SqlTableModel` of `QSqlTableModel` to fetch data from a MySQL database. I want to prevent injection. I ran a union injection and it was easier than taking candy from a baby. The SQL query utilizes the LIKE keyword.

##### Attempt 1 (injectable):

```cpp
QString query = QString("select * from table where col like '%%1%'").arg(edit->text());
QSqlQuery q(query);
SqlTableModel *model = new SqlTableModel();
model->setQuery(q);
model->select();
tableView->setModel(model);
```

##### Attempt 2 (no data is returned, no errors):

```cpp
QString query = "select * from table";
QSqlQuery q(query);
SqlTableModel *model = new SqlTableModel();
model->setQuery(q);
model->setFilter(QString("col like '%%1%'").arg(edit->text()));
model->select();
tableView->setModel(model);
```

##### Attempt 3 (no data is returned, no errors):

```cpp
QString query = "select * from table where col like :param";
QSqlQuery q(query);
q.prepare(query);
q.bindValue(":param", QString("%%1%").arg(edit->text()));
SqlTableModel *model = new SqlTableModel();
model->setQuery(q);
model->select();
tableView->setModel(model);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using QSqlTableModel in wrong way. The common usage is to `setTable` with subsequent `select` call, according to [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqltablemodel.html#details)

```
model->setTable("table");
model->select()
```

Filter can be set using [setFilter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqltablemodel.html#setFilter)

```
model->setFilter(QString("col like '%%1%'").arg(edit->text()));
```

Meanwhile you use a QSqlTableModel like it's a QSqlQueryModel with `setQuery` call. Even if it should work, then according to [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqlquerymodel.html#setQuery) query should be active, i.e. `QSqlQuery::exec` should be called before `setQuery` call.

So, finally, you should use QSqlTableModel in the way as it assumed, like

```
SqlTableModel *model = new SqlTableModel();
model->setTable("table");
model->setFilter(QString("col like '%%1%'").arg(edit->text()));
model->select();   
tableView->setModel(model);
```

If you want to build a query yourself, then you should use a QSqlQueryModel based class, like

```
QString query = "select * from table where col like '%%1%'";
QSqlQuery q(query);
q.prepare();
q.addBindValue(edit->text());
q.exec();
QSqlQueryModel *model = new QSqlQueryModel();
model->setQuery(std::move(q));
tableView->setModel(model)
```